# class CI_Pagination in codeigniter work not properly?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I try to use class pagination of codeigniter, but I came across a problem that the active page of links is always the first page.
My Controller Code

```
<?php
class Users extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->is_logged_in();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/users_manage';
        $data['left_menu'] = 'admin/left_menu_users';
        $this->load->view('admin/include/templates_login', $data);
    }

    function select()
    {

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->model('user_model');

        //$this->table->set_heading('Id', 'The Title', 'The Content');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cib/index.php/admin/users/select';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('users_view')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['num_links'] = 20;
        //$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
        //$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->user_model->getUsers($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/users_manage';
        $this->load->view('admin/include/templates_login', $data);
        //$this->load->view('admin/site_view', $data);
    }

    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
        {
            echo 'You don\'t have permission to access this page.';
            echo anchor('admin/login/index', 'Login');
            die();
            //$this->load->view('login_form');
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

And My model code:

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model
{   
    function validate()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', md5($password));       

        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function getUsers($num="", $offset="")
    {
        $this->db->limit($num,$offset);
        $query = $this->db->get('users_view');
        return $query;
    }
}
```

and my view page:
admin/include/templates_login.php:

```
<?php $this->load->view('admin/include/header'); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('admin/include/nav');?>

<?php //if (isset($left_menu)) $this->load->view($left_menu)?>

<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('admin/include/footer'); ?>
```

admin/users_manage.php:

## Super Pagination with CodeIgniter

```
<?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

The select() function in Controller is the function which uses the class CI_Pagination.I can get the different page of the database.But the links it presents has a problem that the 
first page link is always active.

[image]

As you can see, the data it presents is actually the 11th page, but the active link is still the first page.(Note that I used bootstrap and codeigniter).

Comment: you did not define `$config['uri_segment']`

Comment: @tomexsans,I have a new problem about how to use class CI_Pagination, that is I want to create modify/delete link in one column of the table,but the createlinks() function only can presents what we can from the database.So the question is how can I add one more column in the table for the modify/delete the corresponding row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your code for the active page link:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
```